# how to combine different objects in ms-access each containing different queries into one object

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have created multiple sequential sql query objects for an ms access database. e.g

objectA is named sqlqueryA

and contains the sql code

```
Select a, b, ........From TableA
```

objectB is named sqlqueryB

and contains the sql code

```
Select a, m, n...... From sqlqueryA
```

objectC is named sqlqueryC

and contains the sql code

```
Select x, y, z ..... from sqlqueryB
```

each query is saved as a different object in my ms-access database , how can i create one object containing all queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can UNION:

```
Select a, b,"" as c ........From TableA
UNION ALL
Select a, m as b, n as c...... From sqlqueryA
UNION ALL
Select x As a, y as b, z as c ..... from sqlqueryB
```

Note that sqlqueryA and sqlqueryB could be included as subqueries.

You can JOIN, as long as you have a field with common data:

```
SELECT t.a, t.b,s.m, s.n...... 
FROM TableA t 
INNER JOIN sqlqueryA s
ON t.a=s.a
```

You might like to read:

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)